# Bold text in Label

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, itemrenderer

I am using label in itemRenderer in datagrid and displaying the label based on the validation. I need to show the label as Bold. for this i have given fontWeight="bold";  it is not working and font weight is showing as normal not in bold. Is there any other way to get the text font is in Bold?

Comment: can you show your your some code snippet where you assign itemrenderer and where you assign fontWeight="bold";?

Comment: This is the Label field code :-                                 <s:Label id="lblStatus" textAlign="center" showTruncationTip="true" fontSize="10" height="10" fontWeight="bold" paddingBottom="10"/>   -- this lable id i have assigned in set data() method in itemrenderer

Answer (score 0):

Try this in set data() method of itemrenderer.

```
if (lblStatus)
{
    lblStatus.fontWeight= getStyle("fontWeight");
}
```

May this'll help you..

Comment: before line "lblStatus.fontWeight= getStyle("fontWeight");" type trace(getStyle("fontWeight")); and you can see what you get result from parent. after geting wrong result from parent, you have to set it fontWeight="bold" from parent to make it **BOLD**

Answer (score 0):

Try this yourLabelObject.setStyle('fontWeight','bold');